# Convert byte array to string in Golang template

Tags: go, go-templates

In a Go template, how can I convert a byte array to a string? One the context values I'm accessing looks like this when I print it:
`[34 102 111 111 34]`

This corresponds to `"foo"`.

When I print the type of the value (by doing `printf "%T" .MyValue`), I see `json.RawMessage`, which is a `[]byte`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the builtin `printf` template function and the `%s` verb.

```golang
{{ printf "%s" .MyValue }}
```

You can also add your own function if you want to avoid `printf` for some reason.

```golang
t, err := template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "btoa": func(b []byte) string { return string(b) }, 
}).Parse(`

{{ btoa .MyValue }}

`)
```